# SUMIFS Formula on Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I'm using a SUMIFS on Excel. One of my range columns is filled with dates formatted as "YYYY-MM". I want to sum only the values of another column that correspond with specific years, inclusive of all months. So for instance, I may have 2000-05, 2000-06, etc, and I wanna sum all the values that have "2000-" in them, no matter the MM value. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a small modification to the cells that contains the dates by adding the day to them - any day, you van choose 01 - for example, change 2000-05 to 2000-05-01, then you can use the formula as follows:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B4,A1:A4,">=2000-01-01")
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data are in cells `A1:A23`, you can use the below to find the number of dates that are of the year 2000.

```
{=SUM((YEAR(A1:A23&"-01")=2000)*1)}
```

Note the curly brackets `{}` indicate that you must press `cntrl+shift+enter` when you finish typing the formula. (This is because it is an array formula).

The logic here is that `A1:A23&"-01"` will convert all the dates in those cells from, for example `2000-05` to `2000-05-01`. Then the `YEAR()` function recognises this as a date and returns `2000`.

The `=2000` bit will return an array of booleans for example

```
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
```

We multiply this array by 1 to get

```
1
1
1
0
0
1
```

And we sum this to get the count of numbers with year = 2000.